Complex logarithm and riemann zeta function

The above picture is taken from the book Riemann's zeta function by HM Edwards. I have a question on the last paragraph of this picture which reads as follows,
"It should be noted that for any fixed s there is some ambiguity in the
definition of $\ln(1 - (s/\rho))$ for those roots $\rho$ which are not large relative to $s$.
In order to remove this ambiguity in $\Re(s)>1$ let $\ln(1-\frac{s}{\rho})$ be defined
to be $\ln(s-\rho)-\ln(-\rho)$; this is meaningful because none of the $\rho$’s
are real and greater than or equal to 0. In this way $\ln(1-\frac{s}{\rho})$ is unambiguously defined throughout $\Re(s)>1$ and, in particular, on the path of
integration $\Re(s)=a>1$."
My question:-
$(1)$ What is the ambiguity in
$$\ln\left(1-\frac{s}{\rho}\right)$$ that the author is mentioning?
If I take any value of $s$, I think I can evaluate it. Could you provide me with an example what was the author's intention?

$\log z$ cannot be defined for all complex $z$, not even for all nonzero complex $z$, not if you want it to be continuous.

@Gerry Myerson, could you brief with an example?

An example of "$\log z$ cannot be defined for all complex $z$"? I don't know what you mean. But here's the idea: consider the complex numbers of modulus one, the numbers $z=e^{it}$, $0\le t<2\pi$. You might want to say, $\log(e^{it})=it$, but then there's a discontinuity at $z=1$; as $t\to0$, $z\to1$, and $\log z\to0$, but as $t\to2\pi$, also $z\to1$, but $\log z\to2\pi i$. And there's no way around this. No matter how you try to define $\log z$, somewhere there will be a discontinuity.

Do you understand, Rahul?

Actually, I do understand that $\ln(z)$  couldn't be continuous at all the point. But, my question is a bit different. I am unable to see how putting $\ln(1-\frac{s}{rho})$ as $\ln(s-\rho)-\ln(- \rho)$ solves this problem. If we take a non trivial zero say, $\rho_{1}=0.5+14.1..i$ as an example then I don't comprehend how this produces an error. I would really appreciate an answer through this example.

Then why did you ask me for an example, when all I wrote was that $\log z$ isn't continuous?

@Gerry Myerson, I really appreciate your example. But see my edited comment
